# set out-of-range values to NA

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the one below. 
Data is evaluated every minute by sensor.
`WEIGHT` is a dependent variable. And `TIME` means hour/minute. This data will have accumulated for years. 
The problem is `row[4]`. At this row, weight has a strange value (it is out of
range), which occured by Error of sensor. You must remind that Anyone can't expect when the strange value will be occured.

What I want is making a procedure performing like below.
1. using a method, set the range of variance(set range as from 10 to 50)
2. using for(i) statement, check whether variance(weight) is in the range. 
3. when variance is out of range, impute weight[i] as NA.

```
 ID      TIME   WEIGHT
HM001   1223    24.9
HM001   1224    25.2
HM001   1225    25.5
HM001   1226    12233
HM001   1227    25.7
HM001   1228    27.1
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data is in a data frame called `d`, you can use :

```
d$WEIGHT[d$WEIGHT<10 | d$WEIGHT>50] <- NA
```

You souldn't use `for` loops but vector indexing for this kind of task.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `within` and `is.na<-` for this problem. Assuming your data frame is called `dat`:

```
within(dat, is.na(WEIGHT) <- WEIGHT < 10 | WEIGHT > 50)

     ID TIME WEIGHT
1 HM001 1223   24.9
2 HM001 1224   25.2
3 HM001 1225   25.5
4 HM001 1226     NA
5 HM001 1227   25.7
6 HM001 1228   27.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I couldn't resist:

```
fooweight<-runif(1e6)
wfun1<-function(x) x[x<.1 | x>.5] <- NA
wfun2<-function(x)  is.na(x) <- (x < .10 | x > .50)
microbenchmark(wfun1(fooweight),wfun2(fooweight),times=100)

Unit: milliseconds
              expr      min       lq   median       uq      max
1 wfun1(fooweight) 45.00671 47.68492 49.27120 50.28852 152.4313
2 wfun2(fooweight) 47.74992 51.05204 51.89938 53.00629 156.0306
```

Sorry, Sven, you lose to juba by about 5% :-)